# Read from MS Duo memory sticks with iPad 4 (Lightning connector)

Tags: ipad, camera

I have an iPad retina and would like to load data from a MS Duo memory card (the proprietary format for Sony digital cameras). What are my options?
Unfortunately, using the USB port of the digital camera is not an option as my camera does not have one.

**EDIT**
According to several forums, using a USB memory card reader with the camera connection kit used to work, but recent CCKs apparently do not supply the necessary power for USB memory card readers anymore, so a normal reader might not work.

Answer (score 2):

1. Buy a USB memory card reader that supports MS Duo cards. Make sure that it is compatible with OS X.
2. Attach the card reader to a powered USB hub and connect that to the USB port of your Camera Connection Kit. Insert the card in the reader. Attach the kit to the iPad.

Comment: In my experience, the USB port on the CCK doesn't provide enough power for even the most basic card readers.

Comment: Then you would have to use a powered USB hub to connect it. IMHO, a really cumbersome setup to achieve something so simple.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to put a [MS Duo to MicroSD card adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00176F2RC) in your camera, then put the MicroSD card in the Camera Connection Kit's SD Card reader (via a MicroSD to SD card adapter).